# How to convert list to Array in PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Tags: database, string, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have a simple list.  All columns grayed out have the same value.  What I need is one row with the last column being 'Backorder, Delivery, Out-of-Stock'  -- preferably in sorted in alphabetical order.

The version is 8.0.2.  I don't have access to string_agg() for example.  I thought I almost got there with this query, just trying to try to create an array column:  `select array(select top 1 array_element::text from my_table`

However, I got this error:

```
    [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   subplan->subLinkType == EXPR_SUBLINK || subplan->subLinkType == EXISTS_SUBLINK - 
  query:     17680093
  location:  xen_execute.cpp:7497
  process:   padbmaster [pid=14308]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 1.08s
```

Sample input is:  [image]

Comment: Are you running Postgres or Redshift? These are two different products (although Redhisft was initially a Postgres fork).

Comment: I am connecting to Redshift using Informatica's PowerCenter SQL Workbench.  There I run 'Select version()' to get the 8.0.2 I showed up above.  I hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for string aggregation. In Redshift, this is implemented by [`listagg()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html).

The following query gives you a comma-separated list of all `demande_source` values, alphabetically ordered:

```
select listagg(demand_source, ',') within group(order by demand_source) as demande_sources
from mytable
```

Comment: BullsEye!  Thank you